# How to pass Pointcloud2 message to PCL smoothing algorithm?

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the [ROS PCL tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials) , When I try to implement the [Smoothing and normal estimation based on polynomial](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/resampling.html#id1) reconstruction algorithm  I get the following error
error

> C2664: 'void
> pcl::PCLBase::setInputCloud(const
> boost::shared_ptr<const
> pcl::PointCloud> &)': cannot
> convert argument 1 from 'const
> pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr' to 'const
> boost::shared_ptr<const
> pcl::PointCloud> &'

> ```
>     with
>     [
>         PointInT=pcl::PointXYZ,
>         PointT=pcl::PointXYZ
>     ]
>     and
>     [
>         PointT=pcl::PointXYZ
>     ]
> ```

How to pass PointCloud2 message to this algorithm?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410586/how-to-pass-pointcloud2-message-to-pcl-smoothing-algorithm?/) by [HossamAlzomor](https://answers.ros.org/users/115071/hossamalzomor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The conversion function is named  `pcl::fromROSMsg()` from ros package `pcl_conversions`. Also see answers to #q405219.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0